# Enable Docker Bridge Network on AWS Linux AMI 2

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker

I have created an ec2 instance in AWS. I have successfully installed Docker and am able to get containers running successfully. However, I am unable to get the two containers to communicate with one another. Specifically, I'm attempting to get a Prometheus container (port 9090) to communicate with Alertmanager container (port 9093).

I've tried standard port mappings with bridge network mode, and I've tried host network mode. But to no avail.

Is there any special magic required to get two containers talking to one another on ec2 on localhost?

My Prometheus config:

```
rule_files:
  - 'alert.rules'
scrape_configs:
  - job_name: prometheus
    static_configs:
     - targets:
        - localhost:9090
alerting:
  alertmanagers:
   - static_configs:
      - targets: 
        - localhost:9093
```

The output of `docker ps`:

```
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE               COMMAND                  CREATED             STATUS              PORTS                    NAMES
1c83d903a274        prom/prometheus     "/bin/prometheus --c…"   22 hours ago        Up 22 hours         0.0.0.0:9090->9090/tcp   cranky_banach
d1404c0ee182        prom/alertmanager   "/bin/alertmanager -…"   22 hours ago        Up 22 hours         0.0.0.0:9093->9093/tcp   competent_chatterjee
```

Here is a sample Prometheus log line from CloudWatch:

```
level=error ts=2019-07-19T20:31:36.001Z caller=notifier.go:528 component=notifier alertmanager=http://localhost:9093/api/v1/alerts count=1 msg="Error sending alert" err="Post http://localhost:9093/api/v1/alerts: dial tcp 127.0.0.1:9093: connect: connection refused"
```

Here is the output of `docker inspect bridge`:

```
[
    {
        "Name": "bridge",
        "Id": "8ce9c8be6d071b098930a40873d54c5a6da68bcba91404e360cd0ca4532b365d",
        "Created": "2019-07-19T10:02:37.509745972Z",
        "Scope": "local",
        "Driver": "bridge",
        "EnableIPv6": false,
        "IPAM": {
            "Driver": "default",
            "Options": null,
            "Config": [
                {
                    "Subnet": "172.17.0.0/16",
                    "Gateway": "172.17.0.1"
                }
            ]
        },
        "Internal": false,
        "Attachable": false,
        "Ingress": false,
        "ConfigFrom": {
            "Network": ""
        },
        "ConfigOnly": false,
        "Containers": {
            "1c83d903a2742a95323c626cb2e9a556908e6701790af79d61f8f9cf453acc0d": {
                "Name": "cranky_banach",
                "EndpointID": "23e33b9b0e2f2af24bd6da870bad625fe3d111d92f47a9fdf16d253eba9e3889",
                "MacAddress": "02:42:ac:11:00:03",
                "IPv4Address": "172.17.0.3/16",
                "IPv6Address": ""
            },
            "d1404c0ee18280a80fcfa96e7df3bfa5ff023a58f70b3bac67c23b31de7994df": {
                "Name": "competent_chatterjee",
                "EndpointID": "49b38cbf678abd3942f1d8b2a65f8b353b9e8e228cc84a9311cd1ac6549ddc96",
                "MacAddress": "02:42:ac:11:00:02",
                "IPv4Address": "172.17.0.2/16",
                "IPv6Address": ""
            }
        },
        "Options": {
            "com.docker.network.bridge.default_bridge": "true",
            "com.docker.network.bridge.enable_icc": "true",
            "com.docker.network.bridge.enable_ip_masquerade": "true",
            "com.docker.network.bridge.host_binding_ipv4": "0.0.0.0",
            "com.docker.network.bridge.name": "docker0",
            "com.docker.network.driver.mtu": "1500"
        },
        "Labels": {}
    }
]
```

Comment: Update: I retried and succeeded with running Prometheus and Alertmanager using the host network mode. For some unknown reason I had to restart the Docker daemon before this would work. Thankfully, I'm now unstuck in terms of delivery; however, I'd still like to know why bridge network mode does not work.

Comment: I'm having a similar problem. On an Amazon Workspaces VM, docker bridge network seems to be totally non-functional.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use host network mode when you are looking for container to container networking. Bridge networking (unless you use user defined bridge mode) does not expose containers to each other in the docker daemon. It's security and isolation mode.

https://docs.docker.com/network/bridge/

Comment: On Amazon Linux instance there bridge network cannot communicate externally with the internet.

Comment: @Mr.ShinyandNew安宇 I think I ran into this as well.  Did you figure out how to get this working?

Comment: We eventually got support from AWS and the problem was the workspaces needed to be configured to use dnsmasq.

Answer (score 0):

It should work using either the container's host network or another container's network.

Supposing `prom/alertmanager` is already running, add one of these options to your prometheus `docker run` command.

```
--network host
```

or

```
--network container:$(docker ps | grep "prom/alertmanager" | cut -d" " -f1)
```

`$(docker ps | grep "prom/alertmanager" | cut -d" " -f1)` will return `prom/alertmanager` container id.

More info: https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/run/#network-settings